# Как связать две структуры?

Tags: c++, c, структуры-данных

Сделал курсовую работу. Возникла трудность с одним пунктом из технического задания, он звучит так:

> Создать структуру "акции", содержащую не менее 5 полей, одно из
>   которых называется "рынок" и указывает, на какой бирже продают данные
>   акции

Я добавил переменную char market. Преподаватель говорит, что нужно добавить поле структурного типа и так связать структуры. Вот так:

```
struct Stocks {
   char market[30]; //Рынок
   char name[30]; //Название акции
   char company[30]; //Акционерное общество
   int cost; //Цена акции
   int st_din; //Динамика акции
   Stock_exchange y; //Добавленное поле
};
```

Ещё, нужно вывести информацию о бирже на которой продаются введённые акции(вводятся с клавиатуры или с файла(функции inputdata и fileinput)).

Вывод информации реализован у меня с помощью функции void stockinfo(с использованием поля market из структуры Stocks).

**Вопрос:** *что нужно делать после добавления поля 'y' в структуре Stocks (как реализовать всё выше описанное после этого изменения) ?*

Мой код ниже:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int n;

//Структура "фондовая биржа"
struct Stock_exchange {
    string country; //Страна рынка
    string owner; //Владелец рынка
    int circulation; //Оборот в год
};

//Структура "акции"
struct Stocks {
    char market[30]; //Рынок
    char name[30]; //Название акции
    char company[30]; //Акционерное общество
    int cost; //Цена акции
    int st_din; //Динамика акции
};
Stock_exchange MOEX, LSE;

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Введите:\n";
    cout << "1 - для ввода данных\n";
    cout << "2 - для нахождения самой дорогой акции\n";
    cout << "3 - для нахождения суммы стоимостей акций ММВБ\n";
    cout << "4 - для нахождения суммы стоимостей акций LSE\n";
    cout << "5 - для нахождения общей суммы стоимостей всех акций\n";
    cout << "6 - для вывода акций\n";
    cout << "7 - для выхода\n";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

int count(string file){
    ifstream f(file);
    int k = 0;
    string tmp;
    while(getline(f,tmp)){
        k++;
    }
    k = k / 5;
    f.close();
    return k;
}

void show(Stocks *s,int n){
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
         << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        cout << "Биржа: " << s[i].market << endl;
        cout << "Название акции: " << s[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Акционерное общество: " << s[i].company << endl;
        cout << "Стоимость: " << s[i].cost << endl;
        cout << "Динамика: " << s[i].st_din << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }
}

void fileinput(Stocks *s , int k, string file){
    ifstream f(file);
    for (int i = 0;i < k; i++){
        f >> s[i].market;
        f >> s[i].name;
        f >> s[i].company;
        f >> s[i].cost;
        f >> s[i].st_din;
    }
    f.close();
}

void stockinfo(Stock_exchange EX)
{
    cout << "Информация о бирже" << endl;
    cout << "Страна: " << EX.country << endl <<
    "Владелец рынка: " << EX.owner << endl <<
    "Оборот в год: " << EX.circulation << "\n" << endl;
}

int summoex(Stocks *MX,int m) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++){
        sum += MX[i].cost;
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumlse(Stocks *LS,int l){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<l; i++){
        sum += LS[i].cost;
    }
    return sum;
}

void maxcost(Stocks *MX, int m, Stocks *LS, int l) //Самая дорогая акция
{
    cout << "\nИнформация о самой дорогой акции  " << endl;
    int maxcost = 0, cost;
    string market,name,company;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if ((MX[i].cost) > maxcost) {
            maxcost = MX[i].cost;
            market = MX[i].market;
            name = MX[i].name;
            company = MX[i].company;
            cost = MX[i].cost;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        if ((LS[i].cost) > maxcost) {
            maxcost = LS[i].cost;
            market = LS[i].market;
            name = LS[i].name;
            company = LS[i].company;
            cost = LS[i].cost;
        }
    cout << "Биржа: " << market << endl <<
            "Акция: " << name << endl <<
            "Акционерное общество: " << company << endl <<
            "Цена: " << maxcost << endl;
}

void inputdata(int x, Stocks *s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите биржу, название акции, акционерное общество, цену акции, и динамику акции" << endl;
        cin >> s[i].market;
        cin >> s[i].name;
        cin >> s[i].company;
        cin >> s[i].cost;
        cin >> s[i].st_din;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m, l, method;
    cout << "Введите количество акций в <MOEX> и <LSE>" << endl;
    cin >> m >> l;
    //Создание динамических массивов
    Stocks *MX = new Stocks[m];
    Stocks *LS = new Stocks[l];
    //Заполнение сущностей
    MOEX.circulation = 53;
    MOEX.country = "Russia";
    MOEX.owner = "Yuri Denisov";
    LSE.circulation = 65;
    LSE.country = "United Kingdom";
    LSE.owner = "Donald Brydon";
    while (1)
    {
        switch (menu()){
        case 1: {
                cout << "Выберите способ ввода данных:" << endl << "1 - с клавиатуры, 2 - из файла" << endl;
                cin >> method;
                switch (method){
                    case 1: {
                                cout << "Введите данные об акциях в <MOEX>" << endl;
                                inputdata(m,MX);
                                cout << "Введите данные об акциях в <LSE>" << endl;
                                inputdata(l,LS);}break;
                    case 2: {
                                cout << "Считывание данных об акциях ММВБ " << endl;
                                fileinput(MX,count("moex.txt"),"moex.txt");
                                cout << "Считывание данных об акциях LSE " << endl;
                                fileinput(LS,count("lse.txt"),"lse.txt");
                            }
                            }
                }break;
        case 2: maxcost(MX,m,LS,l);break;
        case 3: cout << "Сумма стоимостей акций ММВБ: " << summoex(MX,m) << endl;break;
        case 4: cout << "Сумма стоимостей акций LSE: " << sumlse(LS,l) << endl;break;
        case 5: cout << "Сумма стоимостей всех акций:  " << summoex(MX,m) + sumlse(LS,l) << endl;break;
        case 6: show(MX,m);stockinfo(MOEX);show(LS,l);stockinfo(LSE);break;
        case 7: {delete[]MX; delete[]LS; return 0;}
        default: cout << "Ошибка!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: почему в одном месте вы используете   string, а в другом массив? Зачем нужна имя владельца биржы, тем более, что обычно биржа не имеет одного владельца?  На бирже продаются акции, поэтому она должна  содержать в себе список акций (лот), а не акция должна содержать биржу. Вы представляете акцию, которая  имеет биржу и не существует  без нее ?.

Comment: 1)От того, что поменять char на string разницы не будет. Просто до этого в этой программе было больше функций, в которых нужно было, чтобы типы данных этих переменных были char. 
2)Поле "владелец" может быть каким угодно,просто мне захотелось,чтобы оно было именно таким.
3)Акция не одна, в главной функции создаётся динамический массив.

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать из функции show функцию stockinfo. 
   stockinfo(s[i].y);

Comment: Работает, но в "y" нет информации, поэтому stockinfo(s[i].y) выводит пустоту. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int n;

struct Stock_exchange {
    string country; //Страна рынка
    string owner; //Владелец рынка
    int circulation; //Оборот в год
};

struct Stocks {
    char market[30]; //Рынок
    char name[30]; //Название акции
    char company[30]; //Акционерное общество
    int cost; //Цена акции
    int st_din; //Динамика акции
    Stock_exchange y;
};
Stock_exchange MOEX, LSE;

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Введите:\n";
    cout << "1 - для ввода данных\n";
    cout << "2 - для нахождения самой дорогой акции\n";
    cout << "3 - для нахождения суммы стоимостей акций ММВБ\n";
    cout << "4 - для нахождения суммы стоимостей акций LSE\n";
    cout << "5 - для нахождения общей суммы стоимостей всех акций\n";
    cout << "6 - для вывода акций\n";
    cout << "7 - для выхода\n";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

int count(string file){
    ifstream f(file);
    int k = 0;
    string tmp;
    while(getline(f,tmp)){
        k++;
    }
    k = k / 5;
    f.close();
    return k;
}

void fileinput(Stocks *s , int k, string file){
    ifstream f(file);
    for (int i = 0;i < k; i++){
        f >> s[i].market;
        f >> s[i].name;
        f >> s[i].company;
        f >> s[i].cost;
        f >> s[i].st_din;
    }
    f.close();
}

void stockinfo(Stocks *s)
{
    cout << "Информация о бирже" << endl;
    cout << "Страна: " << s->y.country << endl <<
    "Владелец рынка: " << s->y.owner << endl <<
    "Оборот в год: " << s->y.circulation << "\n" << endl;
}

void show(Stocks *s,int n){
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
         << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        cout << "Биржа: " << s[i].market << endl;
        cout << "Название акции: " << s[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Акционерное общество: " << s[i].company << endl;
        cout << "Стоимость: " << s[i].cost << endl;
        cout << "Динамика: " << s[i].st_din << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }
}

int summoex(Stocks *MX,int m) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++){
        sum += MX[i].cost;
    }
    return sum;
}

int sumlse(Stocks *LS,int l){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<l; i++){
        sum += LS[i].cost;
    }
    return sum;
}

void maxcost(Stocks *MX, int m, Stocks *LS, int l) //Самая дорогая акция
{
    cout << "\nИнформация о самой дорогой акции  " << endl;
    int maxcost = 0, cost;
    string market,name,company;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if ((MX[i].cost) > maxcost) {
            maxcost = MX[i].cost;
            market = MX[i].market;
            name = MX[i].name;
            company = MX[i].company;
            cost = MX[i].cost;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        if ((LS[i].cost) > maxcost) {
            maxcost = LS[i].cost;
            market = LS[i].market;
            name = LS[i].name;
            company = LS[i].company;
            cost = LS[i].cost;
        }
    cout << "Биржа: " << market << endl <<
            "Акция: " << name << endl <<
            "Акционерное общество: " << company << endl <<
            "Цена: " << maxcost << endl;
}

void inputdata(int x, Stocks *s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите биржу, название акции, акционерное общество, цену акции, и динамику акции" << endl;
        cin >> s[i].market;
        cin >> s[i].name;
        cin >> s[i].company;
        cin >> s[i].cost;
        cin >> s[i].st_din;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m, l, method;
    cout << "Введите количество акций в <MOEX> и <LSE>" << endl;
    cin >> m >> l;
    //Создание динамических массивов
    Stocks *MX = new Stocks[m];
    Stocks *LS = new Stocks[l];
    //Заполнение сущностей
    MOEX.circulation = 53;
    MOEX.country = "Russia";
    MOEX.owner = "Yuri Denisov";
    LSE.circulation = 65;
    LSE.country = "United Kingdom";
    LSE.owner = "Donald Brydon";
    MX->y.owner = MOEX.owner;
    MX->y.country = MOEX.country;
    MX->y.circulation = MOEX.circulation;
    LS->y.owner = LSE.owner;
    LS->y.country = LSE.country;
    LS->y.circulation = LSE.circulation;
    while (1)
    {
        switch (menu()){
        case 1: {
                cout << "Выберите способ ввода данных:" << endl << "1 - с клавиатуры, 2 - из файла" << endl;
                cin >> method;
                switch (method){
                    case 1: {
                                cout << "Введите данные об акциях в <MOEX>" << endl;
                                inputdata(m,MX);
                                cout << "Введите данные об акциях в <LSE>" << endl;
                                inputdata(l,LS);}break;
                    case 2: {
                                cout << "Считывание данных об акциях ММВБ " << endl;
                                fileinput(MX,count("moex.txt"),"moex.txt");
                                cout << "Считывание данных об акциях LSE " << endl;
                                fileinput(LS,count("lse.txt"),"lse.txt");
                            }
                            }
                }break;
        case 2: maxcost(MX,m,LS,l);break;
        case 3: cout << "Сумма стоимостей акций ММВБ: " << summoex(MX,m) << endl;break;
        case 4: cout << "Сумма стоимостей акций LSE: " << sumlse(LS,l) << endl;break;
        case 5: cout << "Сумма стоимостей всех акций:  " << summoex(MX,m) + sumlse(LS,l) << endl;break;
        case 6: show(MX,m);stockinfo(MX);show(LS,l);stockinfo(LS);break;
        case 7: {delete[]MX; delete[]LS; return 0;}
        default: cout << "Ошибка!\n";
        }
    }
}
```